# C# DataSet: How can I know if a column is a of DateTime/Boolean type

Tags: c#, datetime, dataset

In C#, I create some dataset or datatable from some query.

Data which comes from DateTime columns in the database are typed as System.String.

Is there a way to know programatically identify a column as containing a DateTime information ?

Sames question for boolean data which is considered as System.Int32 ?

Thank you

**EDIT1** because it seems that this wasn't totally understood:

```
MyDataColumn.DataType is "System.String" (for DateTime) !

MyDataColumn.DataType is "System.Int32" (for Boolean) !
```

So I can't get the in I want from DataType, otherwise I wouldn't even have posted this.

**EDIT2** And the TryParse() idea has a big problem here, it's more obvious with the Boolean/System.Int32 confusion: If I see "1" or "0" I could think that it's a Boolean while it may as well be an Int32 column. TryParse() has the same flaw.

Comment: If you know the columns name then you could TryParse the values as DateTime or Boolean and curse the DBA. If you don't know the column names then fire the DBA

Comment: Obviously the whole company (our client) should be shut down and all their databases should be re-written, but it's a big big non-it company.

Comment: And secondly, I'm trying to do something very "generic" in which I should not know the columns names at start. Maybe it's simply too "generic" to be done.

Comment: I can't see many alternatives here. You could try to build VIEW with casting to the correct datatype, and then work with these views.

Comment: How could you be generic? If you have a column called 'CustomerName' did you really try to check if it is a DateTime column? How many columns are we talking about? If you introduce some weird controls of this type you will end with an unusable system. The columns affected by this 'disease' should be known somewhere

Answer (score 4):

```
if (myDataTable.Columns["thisColumn"].DataType == System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
{
...
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

To check the containing data you may try to parse its values. so for each value in that column you do like this:

```
 DateTime dateTime;
 DateTime.TryParse("your string", out dateTime);
```

Comment: The OP says: The DateTime columns in the database are typed as System.String

Comment: And TryParse() has a big problem here, it's more obvious with the Boolean/System.Int32 confusion: a value of "1" or "0" could be parsed as a Boolean while it may as well be an Int32 column.

Comment: @user1103990 "1" cannot be parse to `bool`. check this: `bool.TryParse("1", out yourBool);`

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored proc like the follow:

```
Alter proc proc_GetDataTypeValueByColumnName
(    
@TableName varchar(500)='tblAdminUser',    
@ColumnName varchar(500)='Id'    
)    
as    
declare @DataType varchar(500);    
if exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name=@TableName)    
begin    
  set @DataType=(SELECT t.Name 'Data type'FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN     
   sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id    
  WHERE    
   c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(''+@TableName+'') and c.name=@ColumnName)    
-- select dbo.GetDataTypeValue(@DataType)  
select   @DataType
End
```

You need to pass the table name and the column name of which you want to get the datatype 
if you want to get it in the code then you can go for the following stuff:

```
public String GetNumberForDataTypeofColumn(String TableName, String ColumnName)
{
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@TableName", TableName);
    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@ColumnName", ColumnName);
    String result = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "proc_GetDataTypeValueByColumnName", param).ToString();
    return result;
}
```

And there is another way that is :: data Column has property "DataType" you can also check from that like below:

```
dtItems.Columns[0].DataType
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This could be useful, however I was looking to avoid this solution. 1° To avoid having this part of the code bound to the DataBase 2° I thought that on this system (which is used by several companies) I would not have access to System.Tables (but actually I have access). For now I'll just flag it as 'useful' in hope of an easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to see if any column of `DateTime` type exists in your datatable. You need to parse each column with `DateTime.TryParse` to see  if any column gets successfully parsed like:

```
 if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
    return false;

DateTime temp;
if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Any(r => DateTime.TryParse(r.ToString(), 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                out temp)))

{
 //Column exists.

}
```

If you want to get the column index then you can try:

```
var column = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray
                           .Select((r, index) => new { Value = r, Index = index })
                           .FirstOrDefault(t => DateTime.TryParse(t.ToString(),
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                DateTimeStyles.None,
                                                out temp));
if(column != null)
    Console.WriteLine(column.Index);
```

*(Remember to include System.LINQ)*